# Why when drawing a circle in the CustomButton class it's not drawing the circle over the form1?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a class CustomButton that inherit from a Button control.

Then I drag the control into form1 designer from the toolbox. but it's showing a rectangle and not a circle.

What I want to do is when I drag the CustomButton to form1 designer that it will draw the circle on the form1.

I mean that I want the circle to be drawn on form1 and that the circle will be a button control.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Draw_Shapes
{
    class CustomButton : Button
    {
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pevent);

            Draw(pevent.Graphics);
        }

        private void Draw(Graphics g)
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            // Calculate the center of the form's client area
            int centerX = ClientSize.Width / 2;
            int centerY = ClientSize.Height / 2;

            // Adjust the size of the ellipse based on your requirements
            int ellipseWidth = 800;
            int ellipseHeight = 800;

            // Calculate the position of the ellipse to center it
            int ellipseX = centerX - ellipseWidth / 2;
            int ellipseY = centerY - ellipseHeight / 2;

            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 4);
            g.DrawEllipse(myPen, ellipseX, ellipseY, ellipseWidth, ellipseHeight);
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, ellipseX, ellipseY, ellipseWidth, ellipseHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

the result in form1 is a rectangle and not a circle:

[image: drawing rectangle on form1 instead of a circle]

Comment: You should probably remove `base.OnPaint(pevent);` as this will draw a rectangular background. Also, the ellipse size should be equal to the button size (ClientSize). You cannot draw outside of the button bounds.

Comment: Resize the button to 800x800 and you'll see the circle. Are you creating a button for elephants to press? Use the `ClientSize` to fill the circle, trim a pixel from the width and height to draw its border.  Fill first then draw. Call `myPen.Dispose();` when you done drawing.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to derive your ellipse shaped button directly from `Control` as the `Button` class adds unwanted rectangular borders. `Control` also has the `Click` event which you need for a button.

```cs
public class EllipseButton : Control
{
    ...
}
```

We add the following properties. The `CategoryAttribute` makes them appear under the right category in the properties window (otherwise they appear under "Misc"). The `DefaultValueAttribute` makes values other than the default value appear bold in the properties window. Calling `Invalidate()` in the setter updates the UI when a property is changed in the properties window or at runtime.

```cs
private Color _borderColor = Color.DimGray;
[Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "DimGray")]
public Color BorderColor
{
    get => _borderColor;
    set {
        _borderColor = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

private Color _buttonBackColor = Color.LightCoral;
[Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "LightCoral")]
public Color ButtonBackColor
{
    get => _buttonBackColor;
    set {
        _buttonBackColor = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

private float _borderWidth = 2.5f;
[Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(2.5f)]
public float BorderWidth
{
    get => _borderWidth;
    set {
        _borderWidth = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

We also add

```cs
[Browsable(false)]
public override Color BackColor { get => base.BackColor; set => base.BackColor = value; }

protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Parent is not null) {
        BackColor = Parent.BackColor;
        Parent.BackColorChanged += (s, e) => BackColor = Parent.BackColor;
    }
}
```

This hides the regular `BackColor` property from the properties window as we want to set it to the same color as the parent control (which can be the Form itself).

In `OnParentChanged` we set this back color. This event will be triggered when `InitializeComponent` runs and the button is added to the Form. We also subscribe to the `Parent.BackColorChanged` event which allows us to consider changes of the BackColor of the parent control.

Now, we have everything we need to draw the button.

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

    RectangleF rect = ClientRectangle;
    float halfBorder = -0.5f * BorderWidth;
    rect.Inflate(halfBorder, halfBorder);
    rect.Width -= 1;
    rect.Height -= 1;

    using var buttonBrush = new SolidBrush(ButtonBackColor);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(buttonBrush, rect);

    using var borderPen = new Pen(BorderColor, BorderWidth);
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(borderPen, rect);

    if (Text is { Length: > 0 }) {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, ClientRectangle, ForeColor,
            TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
    }
}
```

TO DO: We could react to mouse events and also draw hovered and pressed button states. E.g. we can draw the button a little bit smaller than the given borders and then move it one pixel up and to the left when hovered (this makes it appear like lifting a little bit). When pressed we make the opposite which makes it appear lowered. This effect can be improved by adding shadows. I leave that up to you.

Comment: great. is there a way to remove completely the rectangle borders there is a thin lines on the top and left sides borders.  i mean is there a way that only the ellipse will be show?

Comment: You need to clear the canvas before drawing. `e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);` since you don't call the base `OnPaint` method. Otherwise, you'll get those thin lines and more.

Comment: Okay, I am calling `e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);` now. This is even easier than drawing a background rectangle. Now, I am also subtracting 1 pixel from Width and Height, otherwise it truncates the ellipse a little bit.

Comment: @dr.null it did the trick.  last thing , now i see that the circle on the bottom mostly on the bottom the outer color the border width is not perfect circle at the bottom a small part of the circle is looks like a straight line.  here is a screenshot:  the whole border width the more black color around the circle not smooth enough.  in the screenshot on the right side i resized it bigger so it can see better.  here is al ink for the screenshot image:  https://imgur.com/a/NI4sXy5

Comment: Adding `rect.Width -= 1; rect.Height -= 1;` (see the update code) fixes this problem. I also replaced the auto-properties by properties with backing fields. This enables us to call `Invalidate()` in the setter and makes the changes immediate in the designer or at runtime.

Comment: @Jones Yes, fixed already here. See the edit. As for the smoothness, that's what you get in WinForms. For better results, move to WPF or MAUI. As for the task given by Mr. Olivier `TO DO`, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65338709/14171304) a cheat.

Comment: @dr.null, actually, when you set `graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;`, the result is pretty good in GDI+.

Comment: Agreed. However, understanding how antialiasing (and drawing/rendering as a whole) works in GDI vs. DirectX-Based technologies leads me to saying that, that GDI pretty good result is not pretty good enough. Happy 2024 :).

Answer (score 0):

Let's first define the `Rectangle` where the ellipse is to be displayed:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(ellipseX, ellipseY, ellipseWidth, ellipseHeight);
```

and let's create a brush:

```
System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```

So, let's fill your ellipse:

```
g.FillEllipse(myBrush, rectangle);
```

Comment: I added it to the CustomButton class and still when dragging it to the form1 designer it's showing a rectangle and not a circle.